# using greeter as base for locking app

Tags: bash, python, system-programming

I am a hobbyist (not IT specialist) and just had idea to write some lockscreen app/script to learn and repeat regex. I could use bash or Python, but don't know where to start. Could you point me directions?

We are using Operating Systems based on X (Manjaro and Ubuntu)

And please do not hate me as a noob. I always wanted to have knowledge in programming area, but never been determined enough to spend time on this (my wife hates computers at all). But some time ago I sat down (and started to learn) and wrote Python app to determine time my son spends playing on computer. It took me 3 months but finally it worked as expected - I designed it myself, I wrote including refactoring and the conversion to an exe file, I went through the update because my son broke the first security measures, and I think it's great fun :)

So as mentioned earlier I need some tool (wrote by myself of course) to repeat regex, and I think locking screen will be best. Maybe I could use greeter (In first line it should print some text instead of user, and unlocking password will be matching regex) It is just idea, which I wanted to install on my sons computer too (hes 15 now and learns for IT specialist).

Greeter is only my suggestion. Maybe there is something better to use.

Could you please guide me ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This question is too broad. Narrow it down to a single, precise question.

Comment: Also, regex matching is a bad idea in this case. You would need to store the password in plaintext - which is a big no-no.

Comment: @Panki There is no need to store passwords. If regex matches text it should unlock computer

Comment: More precisely - I need to write lockscreen script described above but I am not sure what are best and not too hard ways to accomplish my idea. That's why I asked here.

Comment: Take a look at sources of other software that does it.  The first one that comes to mind for me is [SafeEyes](https://github.com/slgobinath/SafeEyes) which is implemented in python and can display fullscreen overlay and lock it.

Comment: @Stewart Will try that. Thank you for the first clue ;)

Comment: You should be able to achieve this with Python and something like the python-xlib module, if he uses a Linux system that also uses X. It's hard to give this question a specific answer, since it's a bit too broad.

Comment: Both of us using OSs based on X

Answer (score 1):

I am also a hobbyist, but some things you can try to look at is the documentation for the type of lockscreen manager you have, I.E SDDM (Typical with KDE) and poke around their Settings.

KDE offers an array of API Calls in their engine to interact with these components, A good base point is the Arch wiki's (Even if you don't use arch, they have some of the best documentation I have seen thus far)

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SDDM

SDDM uses CSS and JS, so just figuring out their syntax would be all you would need to inject your custom output.

For GDM I am assuming it would be roughly the same concept

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GDM

Some info about KDE's Integrations

https://develop.kde.org/

I really hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, especially for "some things you can try to look at is the documentation" It is very simple but yet very good point :)